# springboot log file printing in xml format

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I am getting the logs in the springboot application in following format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
  <date>2018-02-07T16:31:40</date>
  <millis>1518001300125</millis>
  <sequence>0</sequence>
  <logger>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService</class>
  <method>startInternal</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Starting service [Tomcat]</message>
</record>
<record>
```

Here is property set in application.properties :

```
logging.path=hello
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
```

Expected logging format is :

```
2018-02-07T16:31:40 1518001300348 2 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/Hermes]> INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 13 Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

What am i missing?

Comment: I am suspecting there is some configuration that sets the logger's file-handler's formatter to `XMLFormatter`. It would be helpful if you show us more of your web/beans configuration (including `WebConfig` class, if there is any)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is having the same issue: Apparently tomcat seems to have it's own logging configuration located in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties`. However by default, it does not specify any configuration for log files. According to tomcats documentation, the JDK/JRE has it's own logging configuration located in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/logging.properties`, which is used as a fallback if tomcats logging configuration file does not exist or some properties cannot be resolved. Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to configure logging through Spring, but I found a work around which is explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236918/5703530)