# Spring Boot log files in standalone tomcat are saved in XML format

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging

So I've been wondering why tomcat in standalone mode saves log files in XML format. This did not happen when I deployed the Spring boot application in Tomcat embedded. I'm using logback-spring.xml for configuring logs. Even if I disable it, Tomcat still saves it in XML format. I even tried to override tomcats `logging.properties` file located in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf`.

This is the XML output I get:

```
<record>
   <date>2018-07-08T22:35:25</date>
   <millis>1531089325236</millis>
   <sequence>325</sequence>
   <logger>org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina</logger>
   <level>INFO</level>
   <class>org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina</class>
   <method>start</method>
   <thread>1</thread>
   <message>Server startup in 11151 ms</message>
</record>
```

This is my logging configuration inside `application.properties`:

```
#logging.config=classpath:/logback-spring.xml
logging.file=/tmp/app.log
logging.file-name=app
logging.archive.path=/var/tmp/app
logging.file.max-size=10MB
logging.file.max-history=30
logging.archive.compressor=gz
logging.pattern.dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

And this is my `logback-spring.xml` configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            ${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<springProperty  name="LOG_ARCHIVE_PATH" source="logging.archive.path" />
<springProperty  name="LOG_FILE_NAME" source="logging.file-name" />
<springProperty  name="LOG_ARCHIVE_COMPRESSOR" source="logging.archive.compressor" />
<springProperty  name="PATTERN" source="logging.pattern.file" />

<appender name="LOGROTATE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>${PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE_PATH}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}_%i.log.${LOG_ARCHIVE_COMPRESSOR}</fileNamePattern>

        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

        <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>

    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>


<springProfile name="dev">
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="prod" >

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="LOGROTATE" />
    </root>

</springProfile>
```

I am very certain, that the configurations on the spring side are Okay, since it worked in the embedded mode. Tomcat seems to be the culprit, but I am clueless on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html) I found out, that tomcat falls back unto Java's default logging configuration, if it cannot resolve the tomcat `logging.properties` file location or certain properties. The default java logging configuration is located in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/logging.properties` and uses `XMLFormatter` for file logs. Spring seems unable to handle logging configuration in Tomcat's standalone mode. I could not find a way to use logback, but instead I overrode tomcat logging file. Below is an example:

```
handlers =java.util.logging.FileHandler,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = INFO

# File Logging
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/logfilename%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10485760
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10

#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.springframework.boot.logging.java.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO

org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.level = WARNING
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.level = WARNING
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.level = WARNING
org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory.level = SEVERE
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = SEVERE

#java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
```

Another option would be to add configurations for file logging into tomcats existing `logging.properties` file located in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties`:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler= java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```